I want to generate Alphanumeric series in informatica, and the logic that I am trying isn't working
I want to generate alphanumeric series like below using Informatica PowerCenter and I am stuck coming up with business logic for the same.
A1,A2,A3....B1,B2,B3,....,C1,C2,C3,...C9..
I have used 2 sequence generator and 1 expression transformation.
1 sequence gen for series of numbers starting from 1 like 1,2,3,4,5...
1 sequence gen for series of numbers that cycles through number 1-9 like 1,2,3,...9,1,2,3..9,1,2,3..
1 expression transformation. Have attached image of ports that I've used.
The workflow completes fine but i am not getting desired output. Have attached the output that I'm getting as well.
outlook of my mapping - (https://i.sstatic.net/fdliL.png)
ports used in expression transformation - (https://i.sstatic.net/qAAPT.png)
output that I am receiving - (https://i.sstatic.net/mTxYm.png)
UPDATE:
I have removed v_char_init as per suggestions and just entered 65 instead and have also implemented the new condition for v_char_new. Now I am facing a different issue.
while the series A1,A2,A3..A9 seems to work fine from B1 there is some issue I couldn't quite figure out. from B it only moves to the next character on the 11th value as opposed to the 10th value, I could be wrong though.
expression transformation
v_char_new
output - 1
output - 2

I think v_char_new doesn't receive an initial value. The expression for v_char_new with initial value would look like "iif(v_char_new=0, v_char_init, iif(v_mod=1, v_char_new+1, v_char_new))". The expression for v_char_init can be more explicit with "ord('A')" (you don't need v_char_init in the expression).

Yup, v_char_init is poorly definded. If you want to keep it, it should be 65 simply. Current expression returns FALSE (the result of comparison of v_char_init to 65). Just put 65 instead of v_char_init and remove the v_char_init port at all.

Hi, I tried implementing both suggestions and the output is slightly different from desired output. There seems to be an offset of 1 row from the second character

changing the order of port v_mod in expression transformation so that it flagged after every 9th row as opposed when it reached 9th row did the trick. Thank you all for the help!.
